# Dynamically set a filter in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-filter, plunker

I want to filter the table according to the criteria selected in the dropdown. Writing val in the newList function does not filter the table. Any Suggestions how to go through this.

- HTML

  ```
  <tbody>

    <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in newfriends">

      <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>

      <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>

      <td>{{friendObj.age}}</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
  ```

  - JS

    ```
     $scope.newList = function (val) {
          alert(val);
    $scope.newfriends = $filter('filter')($scope.friends, {
        val: $scope.searcha
    })
    ```

Comment: Plunkr link : http://plnkr.co/edit/3yOmiIJ9Yu9RfAgmuVA7

Comment: If you create proper search model like search.name then you don't need to use `$filter` in your controller, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code, you are trying to add criteria multiple times, then you want to filter with those criteria.

Here in your JSON there is only 3 property. {name, phone, and age}.

So your criteria should not exceed 3 row and it should not have same thing twice.
If you do that you need to build your own filter. 
Use following code

```
$scope.newList = function() {
  var searchBy = {};
  angular.forEach($scope.newCriteria, function(criteria, key) {
    searchBy[criteria.name] = criteria.value;
  });
  $scope.newfriends = $filter('filter')($scope.friends, searchBy);
}
```

And HTMl as follows

```
<div id="searchy">

<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li style="display: inline-block" ng-repeat="crtia in newCriteria">
    <table>
      <tr>

        <td>
          <select ng-model="crtia.name" ng-options="searchopt for searchopt in searchcriteria " ng-click="searchy.check()"></select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input ng-model="crtia.value" placeholder="{{crtia.name}}" ng-change="newList()" />
        </td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </li>
</ul>  <button ng-click="searchy.generate()">Add Criteria</button> </div>
```

Here is the updated plunker. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/r5OcI366dyvLQ24fFIje?p=preview.

Comment: searchBy[value.name] = value.value;                                                   Can you tell me what this statement does

Comment: newCriteria is your criteria array which contains multiple {name, value} object. While applying filter you need to construct an object like {age: 18}. Where age is your criteria name and 18 is the value. So I did. searchBy[value.name] = value.value. [Here the first value is each instance of newCriteria] and second value is 18 (Entered by user). Modifying the code sample for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to filter based on dropdown selection, then create proper search model like

```
<select ng-model="selectedsearchcriteria"
        ng-options="searchopt for searchopt in searchcriteria "></select>

<!--When you select dropdown 'selectedsearchcriteria' update like 'name', 'age' and so on
then ng-model="search[selectedsearchcriteria]" forms like search.name, search.age and so on-->
<input name="search" ng-model="search[selectedsearchcriteria]" placeholder="{{selectedsearchcriteria}}" />

<!--Here 'filter:search:strict' filter like search.name it is like property based filter-->

<tr ng-repeat="friendObj in newfriends |filter:search:strict">
```

**Also i think you don't need to use `$filter('filter')` in your controller**

Check [update plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EfMaVKZsd4oSOJBwqiB1?p=preview)

Comment: Actually I had to filter in the controller

Comment: But the code inside `$scope.newList = function()` you wrote can be achieved without filtering in controller. If you want to show already selected filter use `search` object.